# In Room, how to specify a parent entity relation in a POJO?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, androidx

In Androidx Room, how to retrieve all entity relations in a POJO?

I have the following database structure, where A is the parent of B, and B is the parent of C:

```
@Entity(tableName="a")
class A(){
  @PrimaryKey
  var id: Long = 0L,

  var name: String = ""
}

@Entity(tableName= "b",
        foreignKeys = arrayOf(
            ForeignKey(
                entity = A::class,
                parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                childColumns = arrayOf("a_id"),
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                ))
)
class B() {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Long = 0L,

  @ColumnInfo(name="a_id")
  var aId: Long = 0L,

  var name: String = ""
)

@Entity(tableName= "c",
        foreignKeys = arrayOf(
            ForeignKey(
                entity = B::class,
                parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                childColumns = arrayOf("b_id"),
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                ))
)
data class C (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,

    @ColumnInfo(name ="b_id")
    var bId: Long = 0L,

    var name: String = ""
)
```

I want to write a POJO that should contain B and all its C's and its parent A:

```
class BAndAllCs {
   @Embedded
   var b: B? = null

   @Relation(parentColumn = "id",
             entityColumn = "b_id",
             entity= C::class)
   var c_all: List<C> = ArrayList()

   //how to retrieve parent A of B? 
}
```

So that in the BDao, I can add this:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM B")
List<BAndAllCs> getAllB();
```

Is it possible to embed "b's" parent "a" as well? Is there a way to idiomatically code this kind of usage? Any suggested best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding the parent A object, just get the relevant field/s from A into the POJO using inner join in the Dao.

Dao:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT B.*, A.name as a_name FROM B inner join A on b.a_id = a.id")
List<BAndAllCs> getAllB();
```

POJO:

```
class BAndAllCs {
   @Embedded
   var b: B? = null

   @ColumnInfo("a_name")
   var aName: String = ""

   @Relation(parentColumn = "id",
             entityColumn = "b_id",
             entity= C::class)
   var c_all: List<C> = ArrayList()
}
```